# Casting the "this" pointer to another type does not violate strict aliasing?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11, strict-aliasing

So if I do something like this:

```
#include <ios>

using std::forward;

template<class T>
struct pod_version final{
    private:
        alignas(T) uint8_t m_data[sizeof(T)];
    public:
        pod_version()=default;
        pod_version(const pod_version&)=default;
        pod_version(pod_version&&)=default;
        ~pod_version()=default;
        pod_version& operator=(const pod_version&)=default;
        pod_version& operator=(pod_version&&)=default;

        template<class...V>void construct(V&&...v){
            new (m_data) T(forward<V>(v)...);
        }

        void destroy(){
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data)->~T(); // g++: warning typed punned blah im allowed to break ur code LOL
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(this)->~T(); // g++: :D
        }
};

int main(){
    pod_version<int> x;
    x.construct(5);
    x.destroy();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: "m_data" and "this" should point to the same place...

gcc 4.8.1

Comment: I'd say the compiler is just not smart enough to figure it out (for some reason). I don't think it's indeed legal.

Comment: Why do you use C-style type casting?

Comment: @Constructor as opposed to function style casting or std::static_cast or? which are you talking about?

Comment: @Mike I'm talking about `(V&&)v...` and `(T*)m_data`.

Comment: @Constructor would you prefer i used std::forward in the first case and std::static_cast in the second case?

Comment: @Mike `std::forward` - yes, `static_cast` - no, you can't use it in this context.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b60c7bfa3546494) the warning.

Comment: @Constructor i was under the impression std::forward and std::move were both just a static_cast to an rvalue is static_cast<T&&>(some_T) and static_cast was just a c-tyle cast so basically all 3 are c-style cast essentioally

Comment: @jrok try with non built in type? and make sure -Wall is on?

Comment: @Mike "and static_cast was just a c-tyle cast" -- That part is not right.

Comment: @Mike Same thing (and yes, -Wall is on).

Comment: @jrok It's because you use implicit template instantiation, which only instantiates the member functions you actually use, and you don't use `destroy` anywhere.

Comment: @jrok Use explicit instantiation to reproduce the warning (`template struct pod_version<int>;`). Simple string `pod_version<int> p;` doesn't create all class methods.

Comment: @hvd Constructor D'oh :) silly me

Comment: so would std::reinterpret_cast be the right thing to do here though?

Comment: @Mike Yes. C-style cast use it implicitly in this case, but if you explicitly specify it the code will become more clear.

Comment: @n.m. could you elaborate?

Comment: It's not evident what you are asking.

Comment: @Mike: There's no such thing as `std::reinterpret_cast`.  `reinterpret_cast` is a reserved word and not a member of any namespace.

Comment: @BenVoigt so it is core?

Comment: @Mike: It's part of the language as much as the multiplication operator `*`.  No libraries involved.

Comment: @n.m. why doesn't it give a warning when i cast `this` to another type of pointer but it does complain when i cast `m_data` to another type of pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `char`, not `uint8_t`.

The type punning rules have a special case for `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`, and ONLY these types.  `uint8_t` is not required to mean one of them.

Note that the whole concept of this `pod_version` class is suspect.  You're forcing trivial copy semantics on types for which they are not valid.  Your code will attempt to call a destructor on uninitialized memory, or on a binary image of an object.  Both will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: changing to `char` `signed char` `unsigned char` did not get rid of the warning. i believe `uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char` ie `typedef unsigned char uint8_t` somewhere in cstdint

Comment: @Griwes: That's not correct.  The standard *explicitly* allows "extended unsigned integer types".  See section 3.9.1, paragraphs 2 and 3.

Comment: @BenVoigt Alright, my brain somehow missed that. It's still not a reason for the warning, unless g++ is so smart it warns basing on name, not the type it names (where "smart" would be partially sarcastic).

Comment: the fact remains that using any variant of `char` still produces the warning.

Comment: @Mike: That may be because casting *to* `char*` is allowed, the reverse is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler correctly complains on the cast of `m_data` because `m_data` is not of type `char*` but of type `int8_t*`. The strict aliasing rules disallow type punning to and from anything but a `char*`, `unsigned char*` or `signed char*`.

Probably, the compiler was not able to figure out that something evil could be implied by converting a `pod_version<T>*` to a `T*`. These are complex types, after all, and the compiler does not know which of the members of `T` you are going to access, it might be an `int8_t` member, in which case the cast would be perfectly ok. After all, the undefined behaviour is only invoked when you *access* the same memory location as a different fundamental type, not when you change the type of a pointer.

In any case, you tell the compiler explicitely "I know what I'm doing" by writing the cast, so any sanity checks are purely optional.

Comment: In particular, the compiler has to deal with the case `struct X : pod_version<X>`

Comment: @Mike: But the "common initial sequence" rule *does* still apply.

Comment: @BenVoigt mhm yes yes indeed... (i dont know what the CIS rule is D:)

Comment: @Mike: That phrase occurs 4 times in the C++ Standard (or latest public draft) and all four times are in a statement of the rule (it's stated twice, no idea why the redundancy)  "If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence, and if an object of this standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of
standard-layout struct members;"

Comment: but it doesn't necessarily have the same initial sequence as T

Comment: @cmaster "Your compiler correctly complains on the cast of m_data because m_data is not of type char* but of type int8_t*. The strict aliasing rules disallow type punning to and from anything but a char*, unsigned char* or signed char*." int8_t is likely a typedef of char, in which case the compiler would see no difference. Also, you are only allowed to cast anything to a char*, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Warnings are not required by the standard. Implementations may warn you for any reason whatsoever as they see fit, or never at all.

<s>For what it worth, gcc 4.8.2 compiles your code silently with `-Wall`.</s> Edit: no, it doesn't.

Comment: and you actually called `pod_version<T>::destroy` ? (to make sure the method is actually getting compiled)

Comment: No I did not. Please post self-contained code that reproduces the problem (read submission guidelines for more info).

Comment: @n.m.: Your comment comes 3 minutes after the code in the question was fixed.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not sure what is meant by 'fixed'. The code is not compilable as it lacks `#include` and `using` directives as of now (22:10 UTC).